# Aligning TextView Center in a small LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

This might seem like a trivial question, but I have found that aligning TextView in small layouts is a pain.
Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_phone"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_phone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:shadowColor="#88FFFFFF"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="0.2"
                    android:textColor="#6d5013"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The background image is a 9patch, so there is padding, but the text is not centered and is cut off. I would post an output image but apparently that's considered spam. I have tried multiple things and still this persists. Smaller text does improve the centering of the image, but only very small text centers correctly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_phone">
<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:shadowColor="#88FFFFFF"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="0.2"
                android:textColor="#6d5013"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Comment: scaleType is not an attribute of TextView. I did try to put layoutHeight="matchParent" but the problem persists.